# How can one seed an PSQL table with the contents of two promise objects?

Tags: javascript, sql, express

So, I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to seed my POSTGRESQL database. My invitations table is a join table that is supposed to take in the user.id and the event.id I have a seed.js file that was moving along fine until I get this error:

```
$ node  db/seeds/seed.js
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = 1
N
{ error: syntax error at or near "N"
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/student_105/Desktop/DateTime/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:546:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/student_105/Desktop/DateTime/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:371:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/student_105/Desktop/DateTime/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:22)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:211:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:585:20)
  name: 'error',
  length: 89,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '1',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
 constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1086',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
```

I don't see an `N` anywhere in my code and I don't want to start messing with a module in case I mess everything up.

here's my seed.js

```
const User = require('../../models/user');
const Event = require('../../models/Event');
const Invitation = require('../../models/invitation');

// get this to work at some point
// const newUser = User.create({"name": "Andrea McKenzie",
//                              "phone_number": "9176746154",
//                              "email": "mckenzie.andrea.m@gmail.com"});
// const newUser2 = User.create({"name":"Anthony Pagan",
//                               "phone_number":"7189169523",
//                               "email":"a.pagan90@yahoo.com"});

const newUser = User.findById(1);
const newEvent = Event.findById(1);


Promise.all([newEvent,newUser])
.then(array => {
  const event = array[0];
  const user = array[1];
      return Invitation.create(event.id, user.id);
  })
     .then(invitation => {
     console.log(invitation)
   })
  .catch(err =>
    console.log(err)
  )
```

What might this be and how can I fix it? And how can I eventually seed my table?

edit: adding Invitation.js

```
const db = require('../db/config');

const Invitation = {};

Invitation.create = (userId,eventId,status = "pending") => {
  return db.one(`INSERT INTO invitations (event_id,user_id) VALUES ($1,$2) 
RETURNING *` [userId,eventId]);
}

module.exports = Invitation;
```

Comment: On line 3 where? That first set of code is in my CL, not my code

Comment: How does `Invitation.create(event.id, user.id);` look like? The `42601`indicate that you have a syntax error in your SQL

Comment: I'll add it to my question,  gimme 5